# Duplicate img with js

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Recently I decided to try to put into practice small projects, which are variations of things from projects done in the classroom.

This one has a simple goal:

I have an image and a button next to it. Every time the button is pressed, it should create an img tag with the same class and content as the first, before the button itself.

```
// From HTML

const content = document.querySelector('#content');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-plus');

// Function

function addImagem(){

    const img = document.createElement('img'); // create img
    img.classList.add('imgQ'); // give this img a class ('imgQ')
    img.innerHTML = '<img src="imgs/bigodes.jpg">'; // give this img a HTML content

    content.insertBefore('img','addBtn'); // insert this img before add button inside div


}


//Event

addBtn.forEach((Btn)=> Btn.addEventListener('click',addImagem())
);


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gats</title>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <script src="script/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="top">
        <h1>Cats! Anyway</h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn-search" type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-search"></i></button>
</nav>
                
    <main class="mid">
        <div id="content">
                <img class="imgQ" src="imgs/bigodes.jpg">

            <button type="submit" id="btn-plus"><i class="fa-thin fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>

    </main>

    <footer class="bottom"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

First of all i've change getElementById > querySelector, then rewrite evething comenting the steps of idea. As it didn't work i read a few questions here and looked in yt. Also tried to remove the forEach, but when i did it a second element, without the img inside appear. In both cases, the button add didn't work.

Comment: Typo.  Remove the parens after `addImagem` in your `forEach` line.  You are not passing the function, you are CALLING the function and passing what it returns, which is undefined.

Comment: @TimRoberts Now it shows **Uncaught TypeError: addBtn.forEach is not a function**

Comment: `var addBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#btn-plus"); for(var i = 0; i < addBtn.length; i++){ btn = addBtn[i]; btn.addEventListener("click",addImagem); }` Maybe this would help?

Comment: @TimRoberts Same error...

Comment: @TimRoberts I deleted the **addEventListener** and add **onclick="addImagem()"** in html. Now it create the espace. Just have to make with border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// From HTML

const content = document.querySelector('#content');
const addBtn = document.querySelectorAll('#btn-plus');

// Function

function addImagem(){

    const img = document.createElement('img'); // create img
    img.classList.add('imgQ'); // give this img a class ('imgQ')
  content.insertBefore(img,document.querySelector('#btn-plus'));
  // insert this img before add button inside div
    img.outerHTML = '<img class="imgQ" src="imgs/bigodes.jpg">'; // give this img a HTML content
}


//Event

for(var i = 0; i < addBtn.length; i++){
  addBtn[i].addEventListener('click',addImagem)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gats</title>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <script src="script/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="top">
        <h1>Cats! Anyway</h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn-search" type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-search"></i></button>
</nav>
                
    <main class="mid">
        <div id="content">
                <img class="imgQ" src="imgs/bigodes.jpg">

            <button type="submit" id="btn-plus"><i class="fa-thin fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>

    </main>

    <footer class="bottom"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Does this work good?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Now it work's, thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes on your addImagem function:
Use the "setAttribute" function so it doenst create a new img tag inside the already existing .

```js
function addImagem(){

    const img = document.createElement('img'); // create img
    img.classList.add('imgQ'); // give this img a class ('imgQ')
    img.setAttribute('src',"imgs/bigodes.jpg"); // give this img a HTML content

    content.insertBefore(img,content.children[0]); // insert this img before add button inside div

}
```

the "forEach" function only works for Arrays. Since you only have one button you can use:

```js
addBtn.addEventListener('click',addImagem)
```

Or you can change your querySelector to querySelectorAll for the addBtn.

Comment: Thank's , i didn't knem "forEach" can't be used without an array^^